# zsh:1: command not found: rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, zsh, capistrano3

I was trying execute `rake` in my deploy with Capistrano but I found a problem to execute because `ZSH`.

```
zsh:1: command not found: rake
```

So I remove `ZSH` from my machine but the same problem persist.

`config/deploy.rb`

```
desc 'My task'
task :my_task do
  on roles(:app) do
    execute 'rake my:task'
  end
end
```

Log:

```
00:00 deploy:my_task
      01 rake my:task
      01 zsh:1: command not found: rake
      01
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host example.com: rake my:task exit status: 127
rake my:task stdout: zsh:1: command not found: rake
rake my:task stderr: Nothing written
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.10.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.10.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
SSHKit::Command::Failed: rake my:task exit status: 127
rake my:task stdout: zsh:1: command not found: rake
rake my:task stderr: Nothing written
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.10.0/lib/sshkit/command.rb:100:in `exit_status='
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.10.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:136:in `execute_command'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.10.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:137:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.10.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:137:in `tap'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.10.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:137:in `create_command_and_execute'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.10.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:69:in `execute'
config/deploy.rb:92:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.10.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.10.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.10.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => deploy:upload_assets
```

Comment: Consider using `Rake::Task["my:task"].execute` instead of `rake my:task`

Comment: My task isn't a deploy task. This is a simple task in a rake file.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with zsh; rather, it simply seems like rake can't be found in the environment's path. Three options:

1. You don't have rake installed. (just install it: gem install rake)
2. You have it installed, but it is not in the $PATH. 
   (add it to path: export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/:)
3. You have it installed and in the $PATH, but don't have permission to execute it. (chomd +x rake)

Comment: Rake is installed correctly. I can running this in my terminal but when I use with Capistrano I received this error. Anyway I remove my ZSH and I fixed this without using Rake on deploy. Thank you.